# Creating a textbox from a dropdownlist in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm a bit new to javascript and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to dynamically create textboxes from a dropdownlist using javascript. Here's my issue in detail. Here is my dropdownlist:

```
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFlightSelection" runat="server" CssClass="dropbtn"  onclick="createTextForm()">
                <asp:ListItem>PLEASE CHOOSE A FLIGHT</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ONE-WAY</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ROUND-TRIP</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>MULTI-CITY</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

As you can see, I have a function called createTextForm() in a separate javascript file that I'm trying to figure out.

```
function createTextForm(){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "text";
    container.appendChild(input);
}
```

Edit: I appreciate the help everyone, but due to my poor understanding and description of the problem at hand I decided to go with a different solution to my problem. What I did instead was create textboxes that are hidden via CSS, and then just show them based on the selection of the dropdownlist.

Comment: So... given maybe a lack of context, `container` is not defined in your function, ie there is no `var container = DOMObject`;

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding. The container is not defined? Keep in mind this was my attempt at creating a textbox I'm not sure if it's correct or not. I was working on this and I think onchange() instead of onclick() is a better option, but the creation of the textbox is still throwing me off.

Comment: Yes, so... what is `container`? `container` could be an integer, a float, a string, some object from a class you created, etc, or a document object model object (DOMObject). What you need to do is either create another container with an id or class that you can use to select it. For example in asp create an element with `id="container"`. In javascript you can select that element by saying: `var container = document.getElementById('container');`, which goes with other variable declarations... ie next to `var input`.

Comment: Ah I think I understand now, yes the action that creates the input was supposed to be the selection of the dropdownlist. So one-way for instance would create a textbox to enter the from city, and another to enter the to city, and another for the departure date.

Comment: Is my container not the dropdownlist @ShanerM13? So is the idea to select via javascript var container = document.getElementByID('dropDownListFlightSelection');

Comment: The dropdownlist can be viewed as a container, but you haven't selected it with javascript. Given that you don't have an element with the id="dropDownListFlightSelection", javascript would return the value of null, and `container` would be undefined. I also had an error in the one-liner I wrote, so I fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

So I understand the intent... but I am unfamiliar with asp and how to create another element in the body... which I could google... but anyways... what you are wanting to do is basically...

```
function createTextForm(){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var container = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    //container could also be obtained with an element with id=my_container like so...
    container = document.getElementById('my_container');
    //or with a class... which returns an array of elements, so you have to select one
    container = document.getElementByClassName('my_containers')[some number to select which element];

    //if you have an element with id='dropDownListFlightSelection', you can use:
    container = document.getElementById('dropDownListFlightSelection');
    input.type = "text";
    container.appendChild(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you currently have, and it doesn't really make sense, because every change on the select will add an input ...

```js
const container = document.getElementById('input_container')
  ,   selector  = document.getElementById('ddlFlightSelection')
  ;
let count = 0
  ;
selector.onchange = evt =>
  {
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = `${selector.value} - ${++count}`
  container.appendChild(input);
  }
```

```html
<select ID="ddlFlightSelection" class="dropbtn">
  <option>PLEASE CHOOSE A FLIGHT</option>
  <option>ONE-WAY</option>
  <option>ROUND-TRIP</option>
  <option>MULTI-CITY</option>
</select>

<div id="input_container"></div>
```